# inline Latex in R markdown

Tags: r, markdown

I have a question about inline R Markdown code:

I have a finished LaTeX table that looks like this:

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|} 
\hline
$\textbf{Vorname}$ &  $\textbf{Nachname}$ & $\textbf{Email}$ & $\textbf{Stimmen}$  \\ 
\midrule[1pt]
\specialrule{2pt}{-2pt}{-2pt} 
\specialrule{2pt}{0pt}{0.5pt}
`r Table[[2]][[1,1]]` & `r Table[[2]][[1,2]]` & `r Table[[2]][[1,3]]` & `r Table[[2]][[1,4]]`\\ \hline
`r Table[[2]][[2,1]]` & `r Table[[2]][[2,2]]` & `r Table[[2]][[2,3]]` & `r Table[[2]][[2,4]]`\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Here, I inserted some inline code (e.g. `Table[[2]][[1,1]]`) for the entries of the cell. Using the notation `r [R code]`. Now I would like to make this table dynamic: The amount of rows if supposed to be be given by a variable `n`.

So I want something of this kind:

```
\begin{table}
[LaTex code]
\specialrule{2pt}{0pt}{0.5pt}
j =0
for (j in 1:n){ 
`r Table[[2]][[j,1]]` & `r Table[[2]][[j,2]]` & `r Table[[j]][[1,3]]` & `r Table[[2]][[j,4]]` \\ \hline }
\end{tabular}
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Without see R code generating a fake `Table`object and a whole rmarkdown file to test it, is hard to guess what you are trying, but anyway my advice is not make a LaTeX table with R chunks code in every cell, but construct first the table as a R dataframe (if `Table` is not already this) and then export the whole  dataframe to LaTeX using `xtable` or `kable`. This last part could be as simple as `library(xtable); xtable(yourdataframe)`.

Comment: ok thank you very much